# Linear equation in modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What restrictions must we place on $F,G,a,b$ such that $\sin(Ft+a)=\sin(Gt+b)=0$ for some $t$?

I'm having difficulty with my computations because $\mathbb{R}/(2\pi\mathbb{Z})$ is not an integral domain.

Answer (score 1):

All we need is to have $Ft+a=\pi k$ for some integer $k$. Similarly, we need to have $Gt+b=\pi l$ for some integer $l$.

Comment: I got this far but got stuck. What are the necessary&sufficient conditions on F,G,a,b such that a satisfying t exists?

Comment: Those 2 condition above are the necessary and sufficient conditions.

Comment: Thanks, is there an efficient algorithm to find a satisfying t, given F,G,a,b?